# VBA Text to columns FieldInfo

Tags: excel, vba

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 5), Array(8, 1))
```

I am trying to use text to columns fixed width.

For this, I have recorded a macro.

I can understand some of the code since I am new to VBA.

However, The above code is not clear.

Can someone explain what this code does?

Answer (score 2):

using the [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel) from @Vityata's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918589/2866644), it means that you made two columns with the two arrays inside the outer array representing the two resulting columns:

`Array(0, 5)` the 1st column starts at character #**0** (the first char) and the type is `YMD date` (type **5**)

`Array(8, 1)` the 2nd column starts at character #**8** (the ninth char = the first column is 8 char wide) The second column's type is `General` (type **1**)

Answer (score 1):

FieldInfo:

> An array containing parse information for the individual columns of data. The interpretation depends on the value of DataType. When the data is delimited, this argument is an array of two-element arrays, with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a particular column. The first element is the column number (1-based), and the second element is one of the xlColumnDataTypeconstants specifying how the column is parsed.

The example:

`Array(Array(3, 9), Array(1, 2))`

> If the source data has fixed-width columns, the first element of each two-element array specifies the starting character position in the column (as an integer; 0 (zero) is the first character). The second element of the two-element array specifies the parse option for the column as a number from 1 through 9, as listed above.

Source: 
*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-texttocolumns-method-excel*